# PostgreSQL query returning non-unicode strings(persian)?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, character-encoding

I have a function in my database with name `rep_request_minor()`

and my database definition is:

> 1. encoding : UTF8
> 2. collation : en_US.UTF8
> 3. collation type : en_US.UTF8

the problem is, when I execute this function in my database, the output is correct, but when I execute it in another program, the output will be wrong :(

so what should I do for converting or casting thr output of my query?

This is my output in the report program

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options: either the characters are stored correctly in the database and your client misinterprets them, or they are not stored correctly in the database.

To diagnose this, apply the `length()` function to one of the strings and see if the result matches your expectations or if it is too big.

If the strings seem correct in the database, your client program probably has the wrong client encoding configured.

If the strings in the database are wrong, the problem is probably a wrong client encoding during data load (e.g. you load UTF-8 data, but set the client encoding to LATIN-1).